# How do I read a file completely, one character at a time?

Tags: c, file, file-io

I'm trying to read a file completely one character at a time with the following code:

```
void readfile (FILE *fp, char *buf)
{
    char *c = buf;
    while (fscanf(fp, "%c", c) == 1);
}

int main (int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    char *contents = (char *)malloc(1000);

    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    readfile(file, contents);
    fclose(file);

    printf("%s", contents);
    free(contents);

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this with an appropriate argument, I don't see any output. I know that I am reading the file successfully, because I see the contents of the file when I print each character, like so:

```
void readfile (FILE *fp, char *buf)
{
    char *c = buf;
    while (fscanf(fp, "%c", c) == 1)
        printf("%c", *c);
}
```

I just can't seem to get the value of `contents`.

Comment: `while (fscanf(fp, "%c", c) == 1) ++c;`

Comment: You can use `fgetc()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
void readfile (FILE *fp, char *buf)
{
    char *c = buf;
    while (fscanf(fp, "%c", c) == 1); 
}
```

into:

```
void readfile (FILE *fp, char *buf)
{
    char *c = buf;
    while (fscanf(fp, "%c", c) == 1) ++c; 
    //                               ^^^
}
```

***Q & A section:***

> *I know that I am reading the file successfully, because I see the contents of the file when I print each character [...]*

You repeatedly print out the characters from **the same location** of your buffer. That is, you don't increment the pointer under which the following characters are stored in. Each subsequent call of `fscanf` overrides the `buf[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not incrementing `c` in the following line.  So you are reading and writing the entire file into a single `char`.

```
    while (fscanf(fp, "%c", c) == 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing the character data pointed to by 'c' every time the loop runs!!
Heres the fix:
`

```
void readfile (FILE *fp, char *buf)
{
    char *c = buf;
    while (fscanf(fp, "%c", c++) == 1); // increment the pointer.
    *c = 0; // marking null at end of string
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

With `char *c = buf;` you assign the start address of your previous allocated buffer and thus always `fscanf` to the first element in your buffer. You should try increasing the address by replacing yours with `while (fscanf(fp, "%c", c++) == 1)`